# Binding when there can be multiple possible values of bounded value

Tags: json, wpf, data-binding

I am downloading json data and need to handle 3 different cases as per below.

Here is my JSON.  As you can see, `parts` can be 3 different things:

- a `null`,
- an `object` holding an array,
- or an `object` holding an `object`

Here is the JSON:

```
 {
        "page_number": "1",
        "page_size": "10",
        "page_count": "7",
        "cars": {
            "car": [
                {
                    "parts": null,    <-- NULL
                    "model": "Honda"
                },
                {
                    "parts": {        <-- OBJECT HOLDING ARRAY OF 2 OR MORE PARTS
                      "part": [
                        {
                          "name": "muffler"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "gas pedal"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    "model": "VW"
                },
                {
                    "parts": {       <-- OBJECT HOLDING A PART OBJECT
                      "part": {
                        "name": "windshield"
                      }
                    },
                    "model": "Toyota"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I need to get all part names of all parts for all cars so that I will get following displayed in my 3 TextBoxes when processing JSON above

- n/a  <-- show if parts is **NULL**
- muffler, gas pedal <-- show if parts is **array of part objects**
- windshield <-- show if parts is a **part object**

So far, I am getting all JSON data using WebClient.  And I added Newtonsoft.Json nugget.

**UPDATE**:

I went to json2csharp and generated classes like this based on above JSON:

```
public class Parts
{
    public object part { get; set; } 
}

public class Car
{
    public Parts parts { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
}

public class Cars
{
    public List<Car> car { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string page_number { get; set; }
    public string page_size { get; set; }
    public string page_count { get; set; }
    public Cars cars { get; set; }
}
```

My Window `DataContext` is set to my ViewModel and I am getting and showing all the data properly except for the Car parts.  I tried binding like this but this obviously by itself can not handle the 3 cases above":

```
<TextBox Name="txtCarParts" Text="{Binding Path = Parts.part}"/>
```

Binding like this shows either empty string or this:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List'1[CarsApp.part]
```

which is not desired.

Comment: What is the question? You cannot parse JSON or you have problems with binding?

Comment: What do you want to show if `part` contains `Array` ?

Comment: Override `ToString()` method in your `Parts` class, and provide string representation of all 3 cases.

Comment: @dbnex14 Hi, consider changing Title of question to "Binding when there can be multiple possible values of bounded value".

Comment: i tried overriding ToString in Parts class to just display a dummy string.  But that did not work.

Comment: @dbnex14 If you are overriding `ToString()`, then your `binding` would be `Text="{Binding Path = Parts}"`

Comment: If you post that as answer, I'll mark it so.  You posted it as comment, so cant mark it.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @AnjumSKhan, here is the solution

Override ToString() in Parts class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    List<string> names = Parts.Select(o => o.Name).ToList();
    return string.Join(", ", names); ;
}
```

Binding:

```
<TextBox Name="txtCarParts" Text="{Binding Path = Parts}"/>
```